# How to resize UIView with dynamic tableview in it?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I am using storyboard.I used one UIButton to show/hide UIView and I already added one tableView to UIView and getting tableView and all.In tableView it is loading dynamic datas.But the problem is that UIView is not resizing with this tableView.I added few constraints and yet it is not working.Can somebody suggest an answer?

Comment: you are set view size  is same as tableview cell size?

Comment: To get yout cell size and set your view.  `CGRect tableSize =cell.frame;
    viewSummery.frame = tableSize;`

Comment: Thanks Vyas. Its working now.

Comment: not for thank, i have up-voted your question, enjoy the coding.... And any time most welcome........

Comment: ok.Vyas..Anyway it was helpfull.

Comment: Thanks, I just added it as a formal answer :)

Comment: But Vyas only first cell is responding to touch event.Others not working? Any suggestion

Comment: Touch event like button touch event otherwise table cell selection???? more idea for show your code!!!!!!

Comment: table cell selection is not working except the first cell.'- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected %@ row", [[[marrXMLData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]);}'

Comment: this method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` called if you are selected the cell, and print the log of your `marrXMLData` array into return selected object values into dictionary get values of is key name is `url`, if your not set your tableview property `selection` is `No Selection`